# OOM in spark processing a VAR

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe that was crated as a global variable (mutable).

```
var output
```

This variable gets updated several times inside different functions via joins as below.

```
def func1 = {
// some code
output = output.join(temp1, Seq("id"))
}

def func2 = {
// some code
output = output.join(temp2, Seq("id"))
}
```

After several of the above function calls, the `output` is passed to another function `performCalculation` where some calculations are performed. My question is, depending on the number of times func1 and func2 gets called in the code, I run into OOM errors (`org.apache.spark.memory.SparkOutOfMemoryError: Unable to acquire 36 bytes of memory, got 0`) inside `performCalculation`.

However, if I write the output before it gets passed in to `performCalculation` and read it back to a different variable and send the second variable to `performCalculation`, it works fine.

```
ouput.write.csv(path)
val newOutput = spark.read.csv(path)
performCalculation(newOutput)
```

Obviously spark doesn't like me using mutable variables and I have to rewrite that part.But, I tried clearing the cache and re-caching `output` inside `func1` and `func2` everytime `output` gets updated but it doesn't seem to help.

```
output.unpersist()
output = output.join(temp2, Seq("id"))
output.cache()
```

What am I doing wrong and what can I do to improve this.